# Adding an Image to an array with polymer

Tags: arrays, image, polymer-2.x

i dont know much about website design but here is what i have. I am creating a blog page and i have created an array with the title and summary. I want to add an image to that then create a card layout for it. I cannot seem to find code where i can also add an image. here is what i have done so far,

```
  <div class="card">
      <div class="imgheader"></div> 
      <div class="container">
    <div id="title">[[item.title]]</div>
    <div id="summary">[[item.summary]]</div>
    <div id="image" img src="[[item.image]]"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<app-footer></app-footer>
</template>

<script>
class BlogPage extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'blog-page'; }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      _blogPosts: {
        type: Array,
        value: function () {
          return [
            {title: 'Mt. Mckinley', summary: ' A journey to the top of Denali. ', image:'web/images/Mckinley.jpg', },
            {title: 'Fishing', summary: 'Catching your largest trout', },
            {title: 'Camping', summary: 'Camping with the family', },
```

i have tried iron image and img src inside the image tag for the first array please let me know of a better way to do this, i dont have much knowledge of polymer i just finished a course on html and css, and i barely know java. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show in loop of `<dom-repeat>` below code

```
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_blogPosts}}">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="imgheader"></div> 
          <div class="container">
        <div id="title">[[item.title]]</div>
        <div id="summary">[[item.summary]]</div>
        <div id="image" img src="[[item.image]]"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

try to change as :

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" itmes="{{_blogPosts}}">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="imgheader"></div> 
          <div class="container">
            <div id="title">[[item.title]]</div>
            <div id="summary">[[item.summary]]</div>
            <div id="image">
              <img src="[[item.image]]">
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Also check _blogPosts array has an image value or empty.